# Rails API ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/goals"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm creating a simple API with Rails and my test for creating a Goal resource is failing due to a `RoutingError` -- but I'm not sure why.

I can see when I do `rake routes` that the `POST /goals` route exists. 
In my my `routes.rb`, I've set up `namespace :api` to be `path: '/'`, so I think my post request should be working.

Can anyone help me point out what I've done wrong?

Here's my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  with_options except: [:new, :edit] do |list_only|
    namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }  do 
      list_only.resources :goal           
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
$ rake routes

   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern          Controller#Action
api_goals GET    /goals(.:format)     api/goals#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
          POST   /goals(.:format)     api/goals#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
 api_goal GET    /goals/:id(.:format) api/goals#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
          PATCH  /goals/:id(.:format) api/goals#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
          PUT    /goals/:id(.:format) api/goals#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
          DELETE /goals/:id(.:format) api/goals#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

My goals_controller.rb

```
  class API::GoalsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        goals = Goal.all
        if is_complete = params[:is_complete]
          goals = goals.where(is_complete: is_complete)
        end
        render json: goals, status: 200             
      end

      def show
        goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
        render json: goal, status: 200
      end

      def create
        goal = Goal.new(goal_params)
        if goal.save
          # render nothing: true, status: 204, location: goal
          head 204, location: goal
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_goal
          @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def goal_params
          params.require(:goal).permit(:description, :motivation, :completion_date, :is_complete)
        end
    end
```

Here's the test:

```
require 'test_helper'

    class CreatingGoalsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
      test 'creates goals' do 
        post '/goals', 
          { 
            description: "string", 
            motivation: "another string",
            completion_date: "01/01/2014",
            is_complete: true
          }.to_json,
          { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }

        assert_equal 201, response.status
        assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type

        goal = json(response.body)
        assert_equal goal_url(goal[:id]), response.location 
      end
    end
```

Here's the error:

```
$ rake test:integration
Run options: --seed 27226

# Running:

E....

Finished in 0.102621s, 48.7230 runs/s, 116.9351 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
CreatingGoalsTest#test_creates_goals:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/goals"
    test/integration/creating_goals_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:CreatingGoalsTest>'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when the subdomain is not set in the test as rails is expecting it, you can override the host that is provided by adding the following:

```
def setup
  host! 'api.example.com'
end
```

to your test suite.

```
class CreatingGoalsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    host! 'api.example.com'
  end

  test 'creates goals' do 
    post '/goals', 
      { 
        description: "string", 
        motivation: "another string",
        completion_date: "01/01/2014",
        is_complete: true
      }.to_json,
      { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON, 'Content-Type' => Mime::JSON.to_s }

    assert_equal 201, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type

    goal = json(response.body)
    assert_equal goal_url(goal[:id]), response.location 
  end
end
```

Further resources on subdomains and testing in rails: [Testing in Rails with Subdomains](http://jlberglund.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/testing-in-rails-with-subdomains/)

Comment: Ah! You're right, thanks so much for looking at this!